# How to check pointers after turning them into an interface

Tags: go

How can I compare pointers that were turned into interfaces?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ContainerInterface interface {
    Check(ContentInterface) bool
}

type ContentInterface interface {
    BelongsTo(ContainerInterface) bool
}

type BaseContainer struct {}

func (container *BaseContainer) Check(content ContentInterface) bool {
    return content.BelongsTo(container)
}

// The following are on a different package

type Container struct {
    BaseContainer
}

func (container *Container) GetContent() Content {
    return Content{container}
}

type Content struct {
    container *Container
}

func (content Content) BelongsTo(container ContainerInterface) bool {
    return container == content.container
}

func main() {
    container := &Container{}
    content := container.GetContent()
    fmt.Printf("%p\n%p\n%v\n", container, content.container, container == content.container)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(content.BelongsTo(container))
    fmt.Println(container.Check(content))
}
```

This returns:

```
0xXYZXYZ
0xXYZXYZ
true

true
false
```

`0xXYZXYZ` represents the same memory direction, but the last call is returning `false` when it should return `true`

Comment: The last returns false because a *BaseContainer is not a *Container.

Comment: One being referenced in the other does not make them interchangeable. `*Container` could, and in most RL instances, have attributes that don't belong to `BaseContainer`, but are essential to `Container`

Comment: @CeriseLimón I guessed that, but how can I make it work? Maybe an auxiliary function that accepts to `*BaseContainer`?

Comment: @Derek For my use case, BaseContainer will never be instantiated by its own, so if they share memory address it means that it is the inner `BaseContainer` of an external `Container`

Comment: @Adirio Either compare *BaseContainers directly, arrange for the interface values to have the same dynamic type (either *BaseContainer or *Container will work).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a "pointers and interfaces" problem it is a "anonymous composition is not inheritance" problem. It's almost always a mistake to try to use go in an OOP kind of way.

When you call `container.Check(content)` , because type `Container` doesn't have a `Check()` method it gets delegated to the `BaseContainer` anonymous embbedded type's `Check()` method.

But methods on embedded structs don't have any visibility of the field of the parent struct or the parent struct itself - so you are actually checking (calling `BelongsTo()`) against the anonymous `BaseContainer` embedded struct not the outer container. This quite correctly returns false.

The fact that this is being done through an interface makes absolutely no difference to this.

If you really did want to code in this way you would have to put a field in the BaseContainer type that pointed to the outer container:

```
type BaseContainer struct {
  parent ContainerInterface
}
```

which would have to be initialised on creation of the parent struct and then the methods adapted to use this. (Although better just to avoid OO style altogether :) )

Comment: "It's almost always a mistake to try to use go in an OOP kind of way." hmm no, OOP =/= inheritance. OOP = encapsulation & method polymorphism. Every time you use io.Writer and io.Reader you are doing object oriented programming. The problem with the OP is he is effectively trying to implement inheritance in Go, which is a fool's errand.

Comment: Very true - completely agree. "Is go an object oriented language" - yes/no/maybe ... it's a rabbit hole that's been gone down plenty on many forums :) I think though to get new people to an idiomatic go way of thinking it might be best to just say not - all of the intros that start adding methods to structs with embedding are a bit misleading and push people in a given direction. Any type can be a method receiver and interfaces are amazing but need to be thought about as what they are - method sets on any type that matches. Best to break the bond and let learners explore the true go :)

Comment: The point is that I'm comparing pointers, you can check how they point to the same memory address (if you move the first `Println` call inside the methods) but one of them is unable to determine that they are the same pointer. Comparing strings works, by the way.

Comment: But interfaces are only equal if their dynamic type is equal, which as I explained in the answer, they are not.

Comment: @GilesW using a function that accepts 2 `*BaseContainer` and compares them shoudl work then?